# Trouble with Remote Sessions and Exchange 2007 Servers

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2007

Anyway, I'm working on some Powershell scripts for work, and I'm stuck on something I thought would be fairly simple. Basically, there are some tasks that I need to perform on our Exchange server that would be great to script. I spent time writing a script that would connect me to our server (on the same domain), and run invoke-command for a few test commands. Once I get the test commands running, I can actually start writing the meat of the script.

For now however, I'm stuck just getting get-mailbox to return any information, which is really just me trying to test that things are working. See the three lines of test code here:

```powershell
$mainSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName TheServerName

invoke-command -session $mainSession -ScriptBlock {add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin}

invoke-command -session $mainSession -ScriptBlock {get-mailbox}
```

I get a "psremotingtransportexception" exception with a "Job_Failure" error. What could this be? I know the snap-in and `get-mailbox` commands work when I actually log-in to the server via remote-desktop and test them out. Assuming I can get `get-mailbox` to function, I could actually perform the more complicated tasks I want to put in the script. The Exchange Server I'm connecting to is pretty old (2007?), so it's not that I'm using the wrong snap-in. Am I missing some credentials? Right now it's not asking me for any, but I tried adding the -credential flag and that didn't help either.

I'm super new to Powershell, so any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the exact error, apologies for the crap formatting:

```powershell
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: The WSMan provider     host process did not return a proper response. A provider in the host process may have behaved improperly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (System.Manageme...pressionSyncJob:PSInvokeExpressionSyncJob) [], PSRemotingTransportException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
```

I should mention that I already tried increasing the shell MB size via `set-item wsman:\localhost\shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024 -force`.  My best guess is this has something to do with the `-credential` flag but so far I haven't had any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official support for remote Exchange administration with PowerShell was added in Exchange 2010, I believe.

[It seems at least one person has found a way to make it work with Exchange 2007](http://peerfect.blogspot.com/2012/10/re-blog-of-my-exchange-remote.html).

Sorry for the link-only answer, but the solution seems to be pretty involved, using impersonation, a special user account created for this purpose, script modules that have to be installed on the exchange server, etc.

Given this solution, I wonder if you could make it work more simply by using a [PowerShell endpoint](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints.aspx) running as an exchange administrator. That would be cleaner than this mess. Basically you would create the endpoint, set the `RunAsUser`, and then you could use `StartupScript` to add the snapin. I really can't say if this will work though and I have no access to a Exchange 2007 environment where I could test it.

Comment: Wow okay!  Our exchange server is pretty old...  I'll took a look at the endpoint article and this seems to be the right direction, but am I creating this endpoint on the server or on my local machine?

Comment: also, is the `StartupScript` where I would put the rest of my script once I get the basic tests running?

Comment: Probably not, that's really for shorter things that you want to affect every session that gets invoked with that session configuration. So you might add initialization code there, load modules, and in this case add a snapin. The rest of your script would likely be executed in the context of that session (like in the scriptblock of `Invoke-Command`).

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I still haven't had a chance to try the endpoint thing, I'm still mostly confused about where to create the endpoint, on the server or on my local machine?  Sorry if this is obvious...

Comment: The endpoint is on the server (more specifically it's the endpoint *of the powershell remoting connection*). So you create your session configuration, then register it on the exchange server. When you call `New-PSSession` you specify `-ConfigurationName 'MyConfiguration'`.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering ya, but I've had a chance to test this out, but it seems that neither the standard configurations or the one I've created via `Register-PSSession` have the `RunAsUser` parameter.  Is there a way to create and set it manually?

Comment: You can't change the parameters of a currently registered endpoint; you need to take your session configuration and re-register the endpoint to change any of the parameters. You set `-RunAsCredential` on the [Register-PSSessionConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849741.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: Well, it didn't end up working, but thank you so much for the tips!  I think it's just time I convinced the team to upgrade our exchange server...